# php count html tag and get its position from string

Tags: php

I have a string in php like this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
<br />
Consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
<hr>
<br />
Ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
<br />
<hr>
At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
<hr>
Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est
<hr>
<br />
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
<hr>
<br />
consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
<br />
<hr>
invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
```

Now after count `two <hr>` I would like to delete rest of string so it looks like this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
<br />
Consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
<hr>
<br />
Ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
<br />
<hr>
```

How can I count and get the secccond`<hr>`position? I've tried with preg_match() but no chance to get the right result.

Advices are much appreciated, thanks for helping.

Comment: use `substr_count($yourstring,'<hr>');`

Comment: tried substr_count() always gives me 0 :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use explode for this function like this :

```
$str = explode("<hr>","Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
<br />
Consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt
<hr>
<br />
Ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
<br />
<hr>
At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.
<hr>
Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est
<hr>
<br />
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
<hr>
<br />
consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
<br />
<hr>");

$new_arr[] = "<hr>".$str[0];
$new_arr[] = $str[1];
print_r(join("<hr>",$new_arr));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use stripos to find the position of your `<hr>` then remove all content after the position of the second.

It should not be hard to write ;)